# How can I get the height of all subviews in a UIView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview

How can I the get height of all subviews in a UIView and store it in a common variable?

For e.g.:

```
var ypos = 20  // initial y position for first UI Controller

ypos = ypos + uiheight  // Dynamic incrementing of y position of other UIView with respect to the height of the previous UIView.

let DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, ypos, 100, uiheight))
DynamicViews.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
DynamicViews.layer.cornerRadius=25
DynamicViews.layer.borderWidth=2
self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)

let DynamicViews=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, ypos, 100, uiheight))
DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius=25
DynamicView.layer.borderWidth=2
self.view.addSubview(DynamicViews)

let DynamicView2=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, ypos, 100, uiheight))
DynamicView2.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
DynamicView2.layer.cornerRadius=25
DynamicView2.layer.borderWidth=2
self.view.addSubview(DynamicView2)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the initial value `ypos` being `20` of is meant to represent the height of the status bar. Note that the status bar can both change height and be hidden (taking up no height). In that case it's better to look at `statusBarFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a loop through the subViews present in the view:

```
var height:CGFloat = 0
for view in self.view.subviews {
    height = height + view.bounds.size.height
}
print(height) //total height of all subviews
```

**Update:**

To set the yPos dynamically for the next subView, run a loop to howsoever many views you want:

```
    var yPos: CGFloat = 20 //initial yPos
    let uiHeight: CGFloat = 100 //fixed height for all views

    let someView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: yPos, width: 100, height: uiHeight))
    someView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.view.addSubview(someView)

    for _ in 0 ..< 3 {
        yPos = uiHeight + yPos + 2 // every time the loop runs, it will add the yPos of the previous view to current yPos
        let dynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: yPos, width: 100, height: uiHeight))
        dynamicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(dynamicView)
    }
```

Giving you the following output:

[image]

The extra 2 in `yPos = uiHeight + yPos + 2` is for padding.

**Update:**

To set label, button and image:

```
var yPos: CGFloat = 20 //initial yPos


for _ in 0 ..< 3 {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: yPos, width: 100, height: 30))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    label.text = "I am a label"
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: label.bounds.size.height + yPos, width: 100, height: 100))
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "sample")
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: imageView.bounds.size.height + yPos, width: 100, height: 40))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle("Click me!", for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    yPos = imageView.bounds.size.height + label.bounds.size.height + button.bounds.size.height + yPos
}
```

Giving me the following output:

[image]

Comment: I want to change the y position of each subview calculating the height of previous subview. Kindly share the source as I am a newbie

Comment: Please be more detailed when asking a question. Your question states "How can I the get height of all subviews in a UIView and store it in a common variable?" and above is the answer. You better open a new question asking in detail what you want exactly. And don't just ask for code, share the code you have tried already. SO is not meant to just get solutions but to discuss solutions.

Comment: eg if first subview is at y position = 20 and height of subview is 100. Then I need to set dynamically the y position of the next subview as 120 and so on for all the next subviews with a single variable. I need the yPos dynamically for every next subview

Comment: let uiHeight: CGFloat = 100 //fixed height for all views. Can we keep the height for each view different? and just keep the yPos dynamic. eg: UILabel height = 30 and UIImageView height = 100 and UIButton height = 40 and then change the yPos dynamic

Comment: Just set it according to your need when creating those UILabels or UIImages. This is when dynamic views of same type are created, and please elaborate your question once and for all. Stop changing your question again and again.

Comment: Can you share an example and output preview as I am not getting the desired output. Sorry for changing the question frequently @MuradAli

Comment: I think you should put in some of your own effort as well, instead of just asking for that exact code that works for you, after all the solutions given to you. Its pretty straightforward now.

Comment: Please can you share as I am not able to get the height of each subview in a for loop

Comment: Edited my answer. See above.

Comment: In the first example you are keeping the yPos variable common and the value for uiHeight common. The first condition is alright that the yPos variable is common but we dont want height common for all other subviews.

Comment: I also want to add a 20 px padding in between label, image and button dynamically

Comment: This website is not meant to ask for solutions. You should checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for how to ask questions and what details to share . Also, you should check this book out: Intro to App Development with Swift by Apple Education https://itunes.apple.com/my/book/intro-to-app-development-with-swift/id1118577558?mt=11 to get a hand on Swift and iOS development.

Comment: I am not getting the expected result from the solutions. It would be very kind if I get help as after reading many blogs I am not finding a perfect solution nowhere @MuradAli

Answer (score 4):

Get all subviews of the current view and use `map` and `reduce` to get the sum of the heights.

```
let yPos = (view.subviews.map { $0.frame.height }).reduce(20, +)
```

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I didn't look at the code in the question.

Comment: I am using swift 4. Can you share the source code for it @the4kman

Comment: But I am getting the yPos as common. I need to add each subview height + y position of the same subview to get the new y position of the next subview

Comment: let yPos = (view.subviews.map { $0.bounds.height }).reduce(20, +)
        print(yPos)
        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:yPos,width:140, height:20))
        btn.setTitle("Click Me", for: .normal)
        btn.tintColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
        let label1 = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: 50, y: yPos, width: 100, height: 20))
        label1.text = "Hi Label 1"
        label1.textAlignment = .center
        label1.textColor = .white
        label1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(label1)

Comment: It's unclear for me what is exactly the goal you want to achieve. If you want to access the vertical end of a view's frame, you should use `view.frame.maxY`.

Comment: eg if first subview is at y position = 20 and height of subview is 100. Then I need to set dynamically the y position of the next subview as 120 and so on for all the next subviews with a single variable